# Can you Self-Host ServiceStack via Named Pipes?

Tags: .net, servicestack, ipc, named-pipes

I need to create a process that is able to have high-performance communication with other local processes. To do so, I'm looking at using [.Net's named pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx), but I'm wondering how easy (or possible) it would be to create a [ServiceStack host](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting) implementation that would do so, that way we can take advantage of other SS features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for .NET Named pipes yet, but this [would make a good feature request](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests).

If you want to have a go at implementing yourself have a look at how [Messaging integrates with ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ#adding-rabbit-mq-support-to-servicestack) where after the message is accepted from the MQ Server it is delegated to the ServiceController's `ExecuteMessage()` API, e.g:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    container.Register<IMessageService>(c => new RabbitMqServer());

    var mqServer = container.Resolve<IMessageService>();

    mqServer.RegisterHandler<Hello>(m => 
        ServiceController.ExecuteMessage(m));
    mqServer.Start();
}
```

A Named Pipes implementation would do something similar but you'll want to delegate to the [ServiceController.Execute()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/48baaaeeace4b72f177ef397c2f0f3eb3c495d4b/src/ServiceStack/Host/ServiceController.cs#L513) instead. A performant implementation is also going to need to execute the request on an efficient use of Threads so the server can process multiple requests concurrently.